# snapshot.data becomes null after half a second

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `pending_appointments` and I want to access all of the documents which have the field `patienduid` equal to the current user's `uid`. Then there is a stream builder, but `snapshots.data` becomes null.

Like when I go to that screen, it shows me the expected results for about half a second and then it changes to 'No appointment found'.
Also, if I remove that 'where' statement, it shows me all the pending appointments which is the expect result, but as soon as I add the where statement which should give me the desired result, it goes back to no appointment after showing me the desired results for half a second.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('pending_appointments')
            .where('patientUid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .orderBy('date')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.size,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  print(_compareDate(document['date'].toDate().toString()));
                  if (_checkDiff(document['date'].toDate())) {
                    deleteAppointment(document.id);
                  }
                  return Card(
                    elevation: 2,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                        title: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                              child: Text(
                                'Dr. ${document['doctor']}',
                                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              _compareDate(document['date'].toDate().toString())
                                  ? "TODAY"
                                  : "",
                              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 0,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        subtitle: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                          child: Text(
                            _dateFormatter(
                                document['date'].toDate().toString()),
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 20, right: 10, left: 16),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Patient name: " + document['name'],
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Time: " +
                                          _timeFormatter(
                                            document['date']
                                                .toDate()
                                                .toString(),
                                          ),
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                IconButton(
                                  tooltip: 'Delete Appointment',
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.delete,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print(">>>>>>>>>" + document.id);
                                    _documentID = document.id;
                                    showAlertDialog(context);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No Appointment Scheduled',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```dart
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
}
```

add this to your code

```dart
if (Snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
if (Snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
  return Container();
}
if (Snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
  return Text(
        'Document Empty',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  );
}
if (!Snapshot.hasData) {
  return Text(
        '0',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  );
}

return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final document = snapshot.data.docs[index].data();
    print(_compareDate(document['date'].toDate().toString()));
    if (_checkDiff(document['date'].toDate())) {
      deleteAppointment(document.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Fix code formatting please, this causes my eyes to bleed

Comment: not working .. its the same.. 
I get to see the desired results for half a second and then it changes to that red error screen saying 'the getter 'docs' was called on null'

Snapshot.data changes to null.. i cant get why

Comment: it will not change to null if you are getting the length from the docs

Comment: it says that the getter 'docs' was used on null.. which means that snapshots.data becomes null

Comment: yes, i see where the error is coming from

Comment: final document = snapshot.data.docs[index].data(); i have update the answer

Comment: Umm.. getting this on docuement.id

The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. (Documentation)  Try importing the library that defines 'id', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'id'.

What to do for it?

Comment: check i use final. Remove the DocumentSnapshot in document, use final.. this show solved the issue... or use Map... recheck the answer again

Comment: not working..still getting docs was called on null errror

Comment: update your question the new code you have edited... let me see.